# how to connect extension with content script in Firefox for android?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-android

I am developing an extension for Firefox for Android, but since tabs APIs are not supported on Firefox(Android), how can the messages be sent from extension to content script?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/Port  I am trying to use this  but it is not working on firefox for android, Only content script is able to send messages but it is not receiving it from background script.